# Scrum should features be delivered within a single sprint?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm returning to TFS from JIRA, I'm struggling to see the structure of features and PBIs in TFS.

Should the features be started and delivered within a single sprint?

Comment: No. PBIs should be delivered within a single sprint.

Comment: So PBIs must have demoable content right?

When does the Feature get demod and completed?

Comment: PBIs should be demoable - yes. Features? not should. when completed? once all their PBIs completed.